# Is it possible for ctypes to access a buffer address allocated in *.dll (e.g. C function return address in POINTER(c_ubyte) ?)

Tags: python

I am trying to import a C function, which return a buffer address of (unsgined char *).
Is it possible for Python to adopt POINTER(c_ubyte) to access the memory allocated in dll 
without perform any additional memory copy or allocation movement in Python ?
It seems that it's unnecessary to re-allocate such memory space by Python since it was already
created by the imported *.dll.

The following is the simplified C code in the dll file:

```
static char gp_huge_buffer[1024][1024];
unsigned char *GetBufferAddress(void){
     //This function will modify gp_huge_buffer data for Python
     return (unsigned char *)gp_huge_buffer;
}
```

And my Python script:

```
import ctypes
mydll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('my dll path')
mydll.GetBufferAddress.argtypes = []
mydll.GetBufferAddress.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte)

# Maybe doing something as blow .... I don't know ???
p_ubyte = mydll.GetBufferAddress() 
bytes_from_dll = byte_array.from_address(p_ubyte)  

# No additional memory allocation by Python, just transform bytes_from_dll to data_from_dll?

data_from_dll = SomeTypeCast(bytes_from_dll)

with open('file.dat', 'r') as fd
    data_from_fd = fd.Read()

    if data_from_dll == data_from_fd :
        print("I need to compare the two group of huge binary data")
        print("Especially one is in file.dat and the other is in *.dll")
```